# How to share print drivers from a 64 bit Windows server to 32 bit client machines

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, print-server, shared-printers

I'm sure this is a dumb question, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the heck is going on. I've looked around and I've seen similar questions of this nature, but nothing exactly matching my issue.

I'm looking to replace my current file/print server. In place of the old one would be a 64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1. I have added the 64 bit drivers to the server, but it's my understanding that I need to push 32 bit drivers to my clients (as they're all 32 bit machines).

So I go into the Printer Properties and select the Sharing tab. I click the "Additional Drivers" button and attempt to select x86. I then point to the 32 bit drivers for the printer in question and hit okay. Then I'm asked to provide a path to the I386 folder (which I do) but every time I click "OK"it keeps asking for that folder again. I end up in an endless loop of trying to show the system where the folder is.

Can someone provide me with some guidance about what I'm doing wrong? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar question. [x64 print driver keeps asking for x64 windows disk](https://serverfault.com/questions/289225/x64-print-driver-keeps-asking-for-x64-windows-disk)

Do what I did but from a 32-bit system.

It looks like the best way to make this work and not ask for the i386 folder is to set the printer through a x32 bit OS.

1. Start > Run > \\servername
2. Right click on the printer you want to add the x32 bit driver to and go to `Properties`
3. `Sharing` tab > `Additional Drivers` button
4. Check the box for x32 > Ok > Point to the location of your x32 bit drivers

Comment: This is what I'm doing but after that is when I'm asked to provide a path to the I386 folder.

Comment: What file is it looking for? If you click browse, it should show the file name. I'm assuming you're missing that in your local copy of your c:\i386

Comment: As far as I can tell it's looking for NTPRINT.inf - when I point it to that file it keeps going in endless loops of looking for the I386 folder.

Comment: Is that file in your local c:\i386 folder? It will usually look for it there first before looking for it in the cd drive.

Comment: I have a copy of the i386 folder copied onto the C:\ drive and the windows XP cd in the D:\ drive and no love.

Comment: Did you try this from the server with the same result (probably, but just checking)? If you click the browse button, what's the default path that it takes you to if you start fresh?

Comment: I did...when I click Browse the default is D:\ oddly enough. I'm happy to see that this wasn't something painfully obvious lol

Comment: Ah I believe this issue has been solved. I tried this from a Windows XP machine (as opposed to my Windows 7 32 bit machine) and was able to make this happen. Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: I found this. If you still have to set any of these up, I would be interested if this works. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverprint/thread/3a71358a-3cd0-4850-9890-86be5d497545/