# Sharing EPSON FX-890 printer on Windows 2008 R2 to 32-bit clients

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-xp, drivers, network-printer

I'm migrating our print server from Windows 2003 to 2008 R2 (64 bit).

I have installed our network printers sucessfully but I'm having problems when sharing Epson impact printers.

The problem is that Windows installs the x64 driver and when I choose to install aditional drivers, the x86 one is not available.

Epson does not have this drivers for download as they come "in-box" on windows.

Because of this, our Windows XP clients cannot connect to the printer.

Has anybody ran into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution to this issue.

1. Download the 64bit printer drivers from the Epson site ([here](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&oid=23730&infoType=Downloads)). You can download XP, Vista or 7 drivers, they are the same.
2. Download the Windows XP 32bit drivers from the same place.
3. Install the printer on the server using the 64bit driver you just downloaded or replace the driver on the printer advanced properties.
4. Follow the steps listed on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/300118/how-to-share-print-drivers-from-a-64-bit-windows-server-to-32-bit-client-machine).

I have done this and now the server shows the x86 driver as available to the clients.

Answer (score 4):

[Epson does have 32 bit drivers for this model available for download](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&oid=23730&infoType=Downloads).

Download, install, problem solved.  ([Use the following procedure to add the drivers for your 32 bit clients](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732946.aspx).)

Comment: They have 32 bit drivers for Windows clients. I forgot to mention that I have downloaded and every single one of them says that it cannot be installed on Windows server 2008 R2.

Comment: @er_tomas  Because you're doing it wrong.  Server 2008R2 is a 64 bit OS, so you can't install a 32 bit driver on it.  You need to add it for 32 bit clients.

Comment: I have downloaded from the page you posted and added them through the printer properties just like you also posted but none of the ones I have downloaded seem to work. The message I get is "The specified location does not contain the driver EPSON FX-890 Ver 2.0 for the requested processor architecture".

Comment: @er_tomas That's because you're Doing It Wrong :-) -- You need to install the 32-bit driver on the 32-bit *CLIENT* systems that will be connecting to the print server. The print server itself, being a 64-bit system, should have the 64-bit driver installed (which you have already done).  If you have any 64-bit client systems those will also require the 64-bit driver.

Comment: @voretaq7 I need to add the driver to the server so when clients install the printer from the share (\\server\printer) the driver gets installed on the client. This works on our laser printer drivers and was pretty easy to set up. The Epson are the ones giving me the headache :(